# Passing data from ViewControllerA to ViewControllerB(QuickDialog)

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickdialog

I'm new in iOS developer and QuickDialog.

I want to pass data from ViewControllerA to ViewControllerB.

It's work but in ViewControllerB i have a problem.

**Example**

In ViewControllerA.m

```
-(void) goToViewControllerB
{
    ViewControllerB *viewControllerB = [[ViewControllerB alloc]init];
    // send data 
    viewControllerB.ownerName = @"TestData";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES];
}
```

In ViewControllerB.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *ownerName;
```

In ViewControllerB.m

```
-(id) init
{
    NSLog(@"init");
    NSLog(@"ownerName : %@", _ownerName);

    self = [super initWithRoot:[self createViewElement]];

    return self;
}

-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");
    NSLog(@"ownerName : %@", _ownerName);
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];

     NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");
     NSLog(@"ownerName : %@", _ownerName);
}
```

In Method init I create Style of thisPage using QuickDialog.

In Method createViewElement I want to show data of _ownerName but it's NULL.

**This is Output of this example code.**

```
>> init
>> ownerName : (null)
>> viewDidLoad
>> ownerName : TestData
>> viewAppear
>> ownerName : TestData
```

I Want to use this Data in Method createViewElement.

How to resolve it.

P.S. I tried to call method createViewElement in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear but it's not work.

Comment: If you're new to iOS, is there a reason why you're not using Storyboards?

Comment: In our project use code only.

Comment: You obviously can't reference the data before it's there.  One option is to pass ownerName as a parameter to init.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your init method of `ViewControllerB` is called before you ever set the value of `ownerName`. See your first code snippet. You could alter your init to accept the string like this :

```
- (id)initWithOwner:(NSString*)theOwnerName
```

and then modify your ViewControllerA code to pass the owner name like this :

```
viewControllerB = [[ViewControllerB alloc] initWithOwner:@"TestData"];
```